# Powershell: How to create a file and write its filename in the content

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to write a short script that prompts the user for a string, then creates 9 files with the submitted string(adding 1 to 9 to differentiate them)

On top of that I need to write to the file its file name

EX: user submits the string "poggers"

Script needs to create poggers1.txt, poggers2.txt,etc in the current directory and then write  "poggers1.txt" in poggers1.txt

Here is what I got so far:

```
write-host "Enter a name"
[string]$word = read-host "word"
for ($i=1;$i -le 9; $i++) {
   New-Item -Name "$word$i.txt" -ItemType File | ?????
}
```

Comment: I tried using AC cmdlet after the pipe and it creates a different file in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pipe the output string to the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
$word = read-host "word" 
1 .. 9 | ForEach-Object { 
    "$word$_.txt" | Out-File "$word$_.txt"
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!